# How to check if any element in a list occurs x number of times with stream() in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Say you have a Collection of cards, containing a suit and a face:

```
Collection<Card> cards = Arrays.asList(new Card('H',6),new Card('H',3), new Card('H',9), new Card('H',4),new Card('S', 1), new Card('H', 2), new Card('D', 12), new Card('S',7), new Card('C', 13));
```

Recall poker rules;
Using stream() in java 8, is there a pretty way of returning a boolean statement if the list contains a flush? (five cards in the list has the same suit)

So far I have only managed to do it by checking each suit manually, like this:

```
long s= cards.stream()
            .filter(x->x.getSuit()=='S')
            .count();
long d= cards.stream()
            .filter(x->x.getSuit()=='D')
            .count();
long h= cards.stream()
            .filter(x->x.getSuit()=='H')
            .count();
long c= cards.stream()
            .filter(x->x.getSuit()=='C')
            .count();
if (s==5 || d==5|| h==5||c==5) {
    System.out.println(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean hasFlush = 
    Arrays.stream(new int[] {'S', 'D', 'H', 'C'})
          .anyMatch(suit -> cards.stream()
                                 .filter(x -> x.getSuit() == suit)
                                 .count() == 5);
```

Comment: Is having more than five not a “flush”? Btw. using `IntStream.of('S', 'D', 'H', 'C')` might be more convenient *and* more efficient…

Comment: I don't know much about poker. I juse used the OP's definition of a flush.

Comment: Regarding IntStream.of(), it just calls Arrays.stream(), so the performance is the same.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the overloads of `Arrays.stream`, that’s another reason I’d prefer `IntStream.of` to make clear that an `IntStream` will be created.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean hasFlush = cards.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getSuit(), Collectors.counting()))
     .values().stream().anyMatch(x -> x == 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not as performant as `anyMatch`, but you can group by the suit and check if you have the value 5.

```
boolean hasFlush = cards.stream()
                        .collect(groupingBy(Card::getSuit, counting())
                        .containsValue(5L);
```